# Inkscape: scale line without scaling arrowhead (marker)

Tags: inkscape, resize

In Inkscape, when I stretch a line having an end marker (e.g., an arrowhead), the marker scales. I'm not sure why anyone would want this. Is there a way to keep the same marker, and only stretch the line? I think we could assume that's what the user always wants, since for example, having different sized arrowheads in a diagram is unconventional, not to mention that it looks like kindergarten art.

Comment: *not to mention that it looks like kindergarten art* – yeah, but so do lines with different thickness.

Answer (score 9):

The following [option in the tool controls](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Transforms.html#Transforms-Mouse):

[image: icon for stroke width scaling]

enables stroke width and arrowhead scaling when transforming a path.

If set, then the stroke width and arrowheads will scale together with the path. If unset, both will be unmodified when scaling.